# Changing the color of the font Excel xlsx

Tags: excel, apache-poi, java-7

I'm trying to change the text color of a certain cell and the code I'm using is this:

```
XSSFCellStyle textColor = workbook.createCellStyle();
XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
font.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());

textColor.cloneStyleFrom(cell.getCellStyle());
textColor.setFont(font);
cell.setCellStyle(textColor);
```

The cell already have a style. I don't know if something changed in POI because I know this way worked in the past.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
poi-3.7.jar 
java 7

Comment: What issue you are getting...Are you performing write excel operation after that... if not.. the change will not appear...

Comment: Your code is working for me. Please, could you edit your question and add the complete code where you are adding the value to the cell and saving the excel file?